# Model for probability of choosing k successful marbles from an urn of a + b marbles

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory

I am wondering if there exists a model for the probability of choosing at least *k* successful marbles from an urn of *a* (successful) and *b* marbles with replacement given *n* draws, where if an *a* marble is selected, it is replaced as a *b* marble but not vice versa (i.e., *a* marbles become *b* marbles if selected, but *b* marbles do not become *a* marbles).

I have come across beta distributions and beta-binomial distributions, but these don't seem to be exactly what I need.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you simply replace the marbles without any altering, then the number of selections required to choose $k$ successful marbles (I guess you want to model this) simply follows a negative Binomial distribution. Now you are altering it, so you just have a sum of independent geometric random variables with probabilities of success $\displaystyle \frac {a} {a+b}, \frac {a-1} {a+b}, \ldots, \frac {a-k+1} {a+b}$ for each selection. I doubt if there is a more condensed form, because even in coupon collector's problem (also dealing with sum of independent geoemetric rvs) there is no closed form.

Comment: I edited my original post to better explain the situation. I missed some keys specifications that I think change the problem quite a bit.